# Python is saying that "account" is not defined pylance

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm following a video tutorial on blockchain development using python and I'm getting this error
("account" is not defined pylance).And this is my code:

```
import brownie
from eth_account import Account
from brownie import accounts
def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = account.load("freecodecamp-account")
print(account)
def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

can someone review this code and see what's wrong with

Comment: Probably you mean `account = accounts.load("freecodecamp-account")`. Also in `print(account)` - `account` is not defined outside the `deploy_simple_storage` function, so it is not defined at the time when you print it.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have to `print()` inside function `deploy_simple_storage` because `account` is local variable and it doesn't exists outside function. Besides you try to print it before it will execute `deploy_simple_storage()`. Other problem is: you forgot `s` in words `accounts` in `accounts.load(...)`